# Should we use node-specific relationships or node-agnostic relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I try to connect various node types from Spring Data Neo4j. **Is this recommended (or discouraged) to use a same relationship type for similar relationship linking different node types?**

**For example**, if we have a Driver class (annotated with `@NodeEntity`), and we want to modelize the fact that the driver can drive different vehicles, e.g. Cars and Bikes, is this better to have :

```java
@RelatedTo(elementClass = CarNode.class, type = "drives", direction = OUTGOING)
private Set<Car> cars;

@RelatedTo(elementClass = BikeNode.class, type = "drives", direction = OUTGOING)
private Set<Bike> bikes;
```

because the driver can *drive* different types of vehicles, or should we indicate the type of the vehicle in the relationship :

```java
@RelatedTo(elementClass = CarNode.class, type = "drivesCar", direction = OUTGOING)
private Set<Car> cars;

@RelatedTo(elementClass = BikeNode.class, type = "drivesBike", direction = OUTGOING)
private Set<Bike> bikes;
```

The first possibility seems more semantically correct, but it seems logical that using specific relationships throughout the graph can allow for faster traversals (no need to test the node types).

**If generic relationships are better, how is this possible to get only the set of cars, or only the set of bikes, using a Cypher query?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general its recommended to be verbose on the relationship type.

The main reason is that your queries will become cheaper. As example assume you want to query for a given driver all bikes he drove. In case of a generic relationship type `drives` this resolved in Cypher to:

```
start d=node:driver(name=<driverName>)
match (d)-[:drives]->(vehicle)
where vehicle.__type__ = 'Bike'
return vehicle
```

Whereas in case of verbose relationship types:

```
start d=node:driver(name=<driverName>)
match (d)-[:drivesBike]->(bike)
return bike
```

The second one is cheaper since you don't traverse to the non-bikes. In the first case you're greedy on traversal and apply then a filter.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a bit to Stefan's answer: You may actually consider having both a generic `drives` *and* a more specific `drivesBike` & `drivesCar.` There may be cases where you just want to retrieve all the vehicles a person drives, and for that... you have `drives.` If you want all bike-riders, then there's `drivesBike.` If you have both the specific and the generic relationships in place, you can optimally query both ways, and having the extra relationship doesn't really impact your database size (though it adds a bit in terms of code, to add two relationship links. Just remember that, if you had only the specific driver relationships, you'd have some type of OR query, with all driver types called out, and you'd need to update your query every time you added a new vehicle type. In this case, it's more convenient to have the generic `drives` relationship.

This idea is actually called out in the book [Graph Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EHQMHEA). You can read more about this pattern there.

Comment: If I use Spring Data Neo4j and the `@RelatedTo` annotation, then using both _drives_ and _drivesCar_ isn't possible, as it would either lead to a `Duplicate annotation` error, either to a duplication of the "cars" collection… Is this a limitation of SDN?…

Comment: I don't know about Spring Data for Neo4j but... you'd need two distinct relationships between the nodes, not one relationship with two types. And Spring data should certainly support this, since graphs often have multiple relationships between nodes.

Comment: You can variably extend your graph entity classes to map different meanings to the one relationship type in neo4j. By the way, unless you have specific performance concerns I wouldn't worry about generic/specific, but about realistic. Computronic cost is the smaller concern, specific to your model and graph consumption habits, but designer/developer/user headache is universal, so until you have a good reason not to, you should just be a realist. I don't usually drive my bike, but I might drive a vehicle, even if it happens to be a bike.

Comment: @jjaderberg I agree about the speed vs headache consideration. Technically, how can you map different meanings without using multiple relationship types? Does it mean having a `Bike extends Vehicle` with a "drives" on the collection of Vehicles? Could you add a new answer? Thanks!